# Navigation-based redirections after sign up

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, navigation, ruby-on-rails-5

My website allows users to browse freely up to the point where they need to be signed in to continue using the service (hitting the "sign up" button and going through the registration process).

Once the users sign up, I want to redirect them to the last *interesting* page they were browsing : it might be the page just before clicking the sign-up button, or something more complex. For instance suppose the user browses a "core" content page, then goes to the "about_us" page, then tries to sign up, I'd rather redirect those users to the "core" content page.

I am wondering what's the best way to do that

- Hidden params in forms ? Sounds annoying to keep track of this parameter all along the form (and keep it when there are errors, etc.)
- Session-based information (some kind of "smart-referrer" url)
- Page visits (eg. using Ahoy.js)

And where/when to do this "tracking" of the last relevant page ? In the controller ? in the view as JS code ?

Any tips to do something like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both via hidden form fields and sessions have benefits.  Using sessions in the controller would be the simplest for you to keep track of as far as development goes however if the user has multiple tabs open it could lead to an odd page flow if they jump between tabs.  This is where hidden form fields work out a bit better but are more annoying to maintain.  I tend to go with the sessions method and do something like the following in a controller action:

```
#This will store the page they're coming from to get to this action.
session[:interesting_page] = request.env["HTTP_REFERER"] || root_path

#Or store the current interesting page within the interesting page's controller action
 session[:interesting_page] = request.original_url
```

Comment: Thanks for your relevant comments on both approaches !

Comment: The hidden input method requires you to do everything with POST (like those #!€ WebForms...) or use javascript to append the path?

Comment: Yes @max, the hidden fields approach is only when you want to control the page flow after a user submits a form based on some specific scenario.  You could also do it via params and a 'get' request when a user clicks a link  however that tends to lead to a maintenance nightmare and I can't really think of a scenario that it would be more beneficial than the other two methods.

Comment: It is possible to have some html forms with method="get". Or at least on rails you can easily add `method: :get` to get this behavior.

I believe I'll go along with the sessions stuff. Correct me if I am wrong, but the session is still preserved across tabs ? I mean after loading a new page, you get the session you had in whatever tab you used previously ? The only weird case scenario would be the user that keeps browsing while filling out th registration form on a separate tab.

Comment: Hey I have some problems testing this `session`trick with Cucumber/Capybara. In case you can help with that too I asked a different question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43504182/capybara-email-resets-the-session

Answer (score 0):

One way is simply to use `HTTP_REFERER` to redirect on sign in. `HTTP_REFERER` is of course limited since some clients do not send it. But you could also argue that if the client does not send the header they don't want to be tracked.

Another solution is to use the session:

```
class ApplicationController
  after_action :set_referrer, unless: :user_signed_in?

  def set_referrer
    session[:referrer] = if request.post?
      request.fullpath + '/new'
    elsif request.patch? || request.put?
      request.fullpath + '/edit'
    else
      request.fullpath
    end
  end
end

class SessionController
  def create
    @user = User.find_by(params[:email])
                .try(:authenticate, params[:password])
    if @user
      render :new
    else
      redirect_to session[:referrer] || root_path
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: HTTP_REFERRER only contains the page visited previously right ? In my case it's not helping since the page I want to redirect to might be arbitrarily far in the history.

Comment: Exactly. If you want to store an arbitrary visit you need to use the session or just a cookie on its own.

Comment: Or you could even use WebStorage if you want to be bleeding edge.