# Capybara email resets the session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise, cucumber, capybara

I need to test a specific flow of smart redirection after signing up in Capybara. Suppose I have several `interesting_pages` in my website, I want to redirect the user to the last visited interesting page after confirmation of registration

Small scenario :

```
When I visit the interesting page "42"
And I visit a couple uninteresting pages
# Note during the visit to other pages, session[:interesting_page] is correctly set to the url of page "42"
When I sign up and I confirm via the link in the email
# At this point I have lost the session[:interesting_page]
Then I should be confirmed and redirected to the last visited interesting page "42"
```

For the actual implementation, I decided to opt for `controller.session[]=` as [suggested in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43472283/2832282). In the controller that renders the `page "42"` I set the session to `session[:interesting_page] = request.original_url`

In development I am successfully able to redirect_to session[:interesting_page] during devise confirmation after clicking on the confirmation link in the email

However when I try to test this using Cucumber, Capybara-email seems to reset the session when clicking on an email link, so `session[:interesting_page]` gets removed when I click the link in the email to reconnect...

EDIT the `When I sign up and I confirm via the link in the email` step basically goes through a devise registration controller and I use Capybara::Email to click the confirmation email

```
# Nested steps for "When I sign up and I confirm via the link in the email"
I fill in "email" with ...
...
I click "Sign up !"
Then I should see "Please confirm your account via the link !"
# At this stage session[:interesting_page] still exists and points to page "42"
And an email should have been sent to "#{user.email}"
And in the current mail I click "Je finalise mon inscription"

# The RegistrationController code I use is similar to devise and returns a pending_confirmation page
# respond_with resource, location: pending_confirmation_path


# Associated step implementations
Then(/an email should have been sent to "([^"]*)"/) do |address|
  open_email(address)
  expect(current_email).to be
end

When(/in the current mail I click "([^"]*)"$/) do |link|
  current_email.click_link link
end
```

Comment: Show your `When I sign up and I confirm via the link in the email` step

Comment: Also the `When I visit the interesting page "42"` step -  It's important those steps have expectations at the end to ensure the pages have actually loaded.  If those expectations are not there it's possible for the session cookie to never get set in the browser.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I just added the steps code. Also I checked via cucumber by trying to load other pages before the step with the email and the session was indeed set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actions in Capybara can occur  asynchronously.  This means that if you don't check for something that should be visible on the page, once whatever action you have executed has completed, and call another visit or action then any cookies that would have been set by the response to that action may not get set, which would mean you don't actually get logged in, or have some important data saved.  In your case that means after (at least) `I click "Sign up !"` you need an expectation for text that would appear on the page after a successful signup.

Another thing to check is that the hostname (and possibly port) of the url in the email matches the ones being used by your normal visits.

Comment: Hey sorry about that, I already have something like this, just didn't think it was so relevant. Thanks for the heads up, it might actually explain other nondeterministic failures I sometimes see in my other tests xD

Comment: @CyrilDuchon-Doris  - Yes very important, also why the 'have_current_path' matcher should always be used instead of `eq` with `current_url`.  I just added one other thing to check since cookies are stored based on hostname (and possibly port depending on browser, etc)

Comment: Darn ! the request host was changed from 127.0.0.1 to localhost, which probably explains the different session_id....

127.0.0.1 is the host name before I click on any email, and after it becomes localhost. How can I uniformize that ?

Comment: @CyrilDuchon-Doris  Yes, that would definitely explain it.  That means the URLs being produced in your emails are using 'localhost' rather than 127.0.0.1  -  You probably need to configure   `config.action_mailer.default_url_options` in your test.rb, which may require locking the `Capyara.server_port` to a fixed port number so you know what port to put in the default_url_options.

Comment: Thank you, I indeed solved the problem with `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
    host: '127.0.0.1', port: port_used_by_capybara
  }`. Thanks for helping